# Incorrect key file for table on Windows

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I have seen from other posts that the issue I'm having relates to disk space:

```
Incorrect key file for table 'C:\Windows\TEMP\#sql72c_28e1c_2.MYI'; try to repair it
```

But I am using a Windows box with 1.58GB free on the C:\ drive and only 44mb of files in the C:\Windows\Temp folder. The total size of the 2dbs which I'm querying are 650mb and the query only links 12 tables.

I'm running WAMP server so my question is apart from the obvious that the query is generating too much data for the space, is there any other reason why this error could be occurring?

Comment: Not quite sure why this has been downvoted?

Comment: Not quite sure why its writing anything to `C:\Windows\TEMP` and only links 12 tables. ONLY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries would write to temporary tables (in this case to C:\Windows\TEMP) if the intermediate result-set would be larger than what MySQL would keep in memory. (In the EXPLAIN for the query, this is represented as 'using temporary')

This particular query has an IN() clause in it, and changing the list of values in the IN() clause meant we managed to get an error code 28 (out of space) out of MySQL.

Seems that Windows Server allocates space beyond what is reported as available so the drive never gets completely full. Freeing up space on the C: made the problem go away entirely since the table index doesn't get corrupted when building the temporary table.